# Rails4 is doing senseless query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building an application to manage the weekly food. My code works fine, but makes senseless queries

the dish (like salad)

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :dish_schedule_day_times, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :schedule_day_times, through: :dish_schedule_day_times
end
```

the day time like evening, morning e.g.

```
class ScheduleDayTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :position, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :dish_schedule_day_time
end
```

and the association (you can eat salad in the morning, in the evening ...)

```
class DishScheduleDayTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dish
  belongs_to :schedule_day_time
end
```

I have a simple form to create a dish

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%=f.label :name, class: 'control-label' %>
    <%=f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%=f.label :schedule_day_time_ids, class: 'control-label' %>
    <%=f.collection_check_boxes :schedule_day_time_ids, ScheduleDayTime.all, :id, :name  %>
  </div>
```

the controller create method

```
def create
  @dish = Dish.new
  @dish.attributes = dish_params
  render :new and return unless @dish.save
end

private

def dish_params
  params.require(:dish).permit(:name, :public, schedule_day_time_ids: [])
end
```

now in the logs

```
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Dish Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `dishes` WHERE (`dishes`.`name` = BINARY 'test' AND `dishes`.`user_id` = 1) LIMIT 1
  ScheduleDayTime Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `schedule_day_times` WHERE (`schedule_day_times`.`name` = BINARY 'Frühstück' AND `schedule_day_times`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
  ScheduleDayTime Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `schedule_day_times` WHERE (`schedule_day_times`.`position` = BINARY 1 AND `schedule_day_times`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `dishes` (`name`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test', 1, '2016-03-07 19:27:27', '2016-03-07 19:27:27')
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `dish_schedule_day_times` (`schedule_day_time_id`, `dish_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 1, '2016-03-07 19:27:27', '2016-03-07 19:27:27')
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
```

the queries which are confusing are the `ScheduleDayTime Exists` checks. I don't want to create a `ScheduleDayTime` and I don't see any implementation to do this. Why is `ActiveRecord` searching for a unique `ScheduleDayTime`?

update:

and how can I prevent it?

Comment: The queries are from your `validates :name` and `validates :position` on `ScheduleDayTime` class, similar implementation can be seen for `Dish` class's `validates :name`. You are saving a new record and that your requirement is to ensure the three attributes in `Dish` and `ScheduleDayTime` are valid, the extra queries, one for `Dish Exists` and two for `ScheduleDayTime Exists` executed.

Answer (score 1):

Those queries are triggered by `rails` behind the scenes to ensure your `validations` are satisfied.

In your case:

Dish Exists is triggered by `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true` in your `Dish` model.

ScheduleDayTime Exists is triggered by one for each `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true` and `validates :position, presence: true, uniqueness: true` in your `ScheduleDayTime` model.

Comment: thats make sence but why? i didn't create a `ScheduleDayTime`. i just select existing `ScheduleDayTime` and push it via `schedule_day_time_ids` to `Dish`